# Can we get a few "This belongs on X stack exchange" options?

Tags: feature-request

We have  a close reason that this belongs on another stack exchange site but we have no sites to choose from.

Obvious ones include personal finance, philosophy and (when they graduate from beta) politics and open source.

Oh, and obviously gardening :-)

Comment: Quite possibly. Is this where you're finding a lot of off-topic questions would be on-topic? Let me see if I can pull out some stats...

Comment: I was under the impression that (as a structural property of SE) there is no option to "vote to migrate to X". Instead, one votes to close and comments that "this would be better on Politics", and the mods look at the post and the suggestions and decide to do it, or not.

Comment: @user6726: It is possible to set up a list of 'target sites'  for any particular SE site; thereafter those with enough rep can vote directly to transfer. The transfer is still dependent on acceptance by the target site's moderators (unless for transfer to the meta), but it is a simpler process once SE staff have activated the list. It does require the users and mods of the origin site to agree on a list of targets, which is presumably what Dale is recommending/starting off.

Answer (score 4):

Our rule of thumb for migration paths is to set them up on an as-needed basis. Even before formal migration paths exist, moderators may migrate to any site, and users may flag questions to request migration. When we see significant numbers of questions moving from one site to another (and not being rejected by the destination), we'll think about setting up a path. Yes, this is pretty subjective. But it works well enough for a system that's already an edge case.

For what it's worth, as I write this, Law doesn't have outbound migrations to any site at the rate of even a single question a week over the past three months.